# How can we navigate to 2 differnent screens from a screen in android?

Tags: android

I have created a home screen in my application and I have added 2 buttons on my Home screen. I want to navigate from my home screen to 2 differnt screens on click of these buttons i.e. on pressing the first button I should navigate to a new screen and on pressing the second button I should navigate to another screen. plz help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to call new activity on button's onClick Event and you have to decalare those two activity in manifest file.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();

    switch (id) 
    {

    case R.id.firstButton:

            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),First.class));
            finish();
            break;

    case R.id.SecondButton:

            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),Second.class));
            finish();
            break;
}
}
```

---

```
<activity android:name=".First" android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:noHistory="true">
</activity>

 <activity android:name=".Second" android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:noHistory="true">
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create two new Activities in onClick method start the desired activity. For detailed explanation check here http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#opennewscreen